# Save output of command that modifies environment into a variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables, output

How to save output of a command that modifies environment into a variable?

I'm using bash shell.

Assume that I have:

```
function f () { a=3; b=4 ; echo "`date`: $a $b"; }
```

And now, I can use commands to run `f`:

```
$ a=0; b=0; f; echo $a; echo $b; echo $c
Sat Jun 28 21:27:08 CEST 2014: 3 4
3
4
```

but I would like to save output of `f` to variable `c`, so I tried:

```
a=0; b=0; c=""; c=$(f); echo $a; echo $b; echo $c
```

but unfortunatelly, I've got:

```
0
0
Sat Jun 28 21:28:03 CEST 2014: 3 4
```

so I don't have any environment change here.

How to save output of command (not only function) to variable and save environmental changes?

I know that `$(...)` opens new subshell and that is the problem, but is it possible to do some workaround?

Comment: Right, so the issue is that `$a` and `$b` are local variables in your `f` function. You could `export` them, but that seems sketchy.

Comment: @HalosGhost: No, I don’t think so. Look at the first example: `…; f; echo $a; …` results in `3` being echoed, so `f` is modifying a shell variable (and not just its own local variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Bash 4 or later, you can use [coprocesses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Coprocesses-1):

```
function f () { a=3; b=4 ; echo "`date`: $a $b"; }
coproc cat
f >&${COPROC[1]}
exec {COPROC[1]}>&-
read c <&${COPROC[0]}
echo a $a
echo b $b
echo c $c
```

will output

```
a 3
b 4
c Sun Jun 29 10:08:15 NZST 2014: 3 4
```

`coproc` creates a new process running a given command (here, `cat`). It saves the PID into `COPROC_PID` and standard output/input file descriptors into an array `COPROC` (just like [`pipe(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html), or see [here](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man2/pipe.2.php) or [here](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pipe&sektion=2)).

Here we run the function with standard output pointed at our coprocess running `cat`, and then [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtin-Commands) from it. Since `cat` just spits its input back out, we get the output of the function into our variable. `exec {COPROC[1]}>&-` just closes the file descriptor so that `cat` doesn't keep waiting forever.

---

Note that `read` takes only one line at a time. You can use `mapfile` to get an array of lines, or just use the file descriptor however you want to use it in a different way.

`exec {COPROC[1]}>&-` works in current versions of Bash, but earlier 4-series versions require you to save the file descriptor into a simple variable first: `fd=${COPROC[1]}; exec {fd}>&-`. If your variable is unset it will close standard output.

---

If you're using a 3-series version of Bash, you can get the same effect with [`mkfifo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkfifo.html), but it's not much better than using an actual file at that point.

Comment: I can use only bash 3.1. The pipes are hard to use. Does mktemp and is the only option? Aren't here special syntax or option to run command and get output but with environment changes?

Comment: You can use mkfifo to make a named pipe as a substitute for coproc, which doesn't involve actually writing the data to disk. With that you'd redirect output to the fifo and input from it instead of the coprocess. Otherwise no.

Comment: +1 for adapting my answer not to use a file. But, in my tests, the `exec {COPROC[1]}>&-` command (at least sometimes) terminates the coprocess _immediately_, so its output is no longer available to be read. `coproc { cat; sleep 1; }` seems to work better. (You may need to increase the `1` if you’re reading more than one line.)

Comment: This seems overly complex. Also, a FIFO is an actual file - and so are the files your coprocesses are using to relay data back and forth. Still, even if you don't want to use parameter expansion, couldn't you just: `f() { a=1 b=2 ; c="$(date): $a $b" ; echo "$c" ; }`?

Comment: @mikeserv: the coprocess handles certainly are not "actual files"; they're opposite ends of an anonymous pipe.

Comment: As for complexity, the question asks for a workaround to capture standard output of a function in the same shell; this is that workaround. As far as I know it's the only one that doesn't involve writing to disk. The actual function must be more complicated than the example or the question wouldn't be worth asking, so command substitution presumably doesn't cut it.

Comment: @MichaelHomer - anonymous pipes *are* files. The same way `stdin` and `stdout` are files. These are all files. And if you want a *file* on input or output just set one. `f() { cat <&4 ; } 4<<HEREDOC\n${c=$(date) $((a=3)) $((b=4))}\nHEREDOC\n`

Comment: There is a conventional, well-understood meaning of "actual file" in use here that you're wilfully disregarding.

Comment: @MichaelHomer - that is a pretty bold statement. The only conventional understanding of *files* that I have is that in Unix *everything* is a file. And actually, I'm really not trying to nitpick - but it really is easier for me - and as I think - for others to remember that file streams and descriptors behave differently than arguments and environment variables. They're always only a bytestream - there is an offset and an in/out radix and they must be parsed.

Comment: "Actual file" meant **a file on disk**, as understood by everyone here except, allegedly, you. Nobody has ever implied or permitted a reasonable reader to infer that either of them was the same as arguments or environment variables. I am not interested in continuing this discussion.

Comment: Actually, i think you meant *allegedly understood by everyone here*...

Answer (score 2):

If you're already counting on the body of `f` executing in the same shell as the caller, and thus being able to modify variables like `a` and `b`, why not make the function just set `c` as well?  In other words:

```
$ function f () { a=3; b=4 ; c=$(echo "$(date): $a $b"); }
$ a=0; b=0; f; echo $a; echo $b; echo $c
3
4
Mon Jun 30 14:32:00 EDT 2014: 3 4
```

One possible reason may be that the output variable needs to have different names (c1, c2, etc) when called in different places, but you could address that by having the function set c_TEMP and having the callers do `c1=$c_TEMP` etc.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a kluge, but try

```
f > c.file
c=$(cat c.file)
```

(and, optionally, `rm c.file`).

Comment: Thank you. That is simple answer, and works, but have some drawbacks. I know that I can use `mktemp`, but I would like not to create additional files.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign all of the variables and write the output at the same time.

```
f() { c= ; echo "${c:=$(date): $((a=3)) $((b=4))}" ; }
```

Now if you do:

```
f ; echo "$a $b $c"
```

Your output is:

```
Tue Jul  1 04:58:17 PDT 2014: 3 4
3 4 Tue Jul  1 04:58:17 PDT 2014: 3 4
```

Note that this is fully POSIX portable code. I initially set `c=` to the `''` null string because parameter expansion limits concurrent variable assignment + evaluation to either only numeric *(like `$((var=num))`)* or from null or nonexistent values - or, in other words, you can't concurrently set *and* evaluate a variable to an arbitrary string if that variable is already assigned a value. So I just ensure that it is empty before trying. If I did not empty `c` before attempting to assign it the expansion would only return the old value.

Just to demonstrate:

```
sh -c '
    c=oldval a=1
    echo ${c:=newval} $((a=a+a))
'
###OUTPUT###
oldval 2
```

`newval` is *not* assigned to `$c` inline because `oldval` is expanded into `${word}`, whereas the inline `$((`arithmetic`=`assignment`))` always occurs. But if `$c` *has no* `oldval` and is empty or unset...

```
sh -c '
    c=oldval a=1
    echo ${c:=newval} $((a=a+a)) 
    c= a=$((a+a))
    echo ${c:=newval} $((a=a+a))
'
###OUTPUT###
oldval 2
newval 8
```

...then `newval` is at once assigned to and expanded into `$c`.

All other ways to do this involve some form of secondary evaluation. For example, let's say I wished to assign the output of `f()` to a variable named `name` at one point and `var` at another. As currently written, this will not work without setting the var in the caller's scope. A different way could look like this, though:

```
f(){ fout_name= fout= set -- "${1##[0-9]*}" "${1%%*[![:alnum:]]*}"
    (: ${2:?invalid or unspecified param - name set to fout}) || set --
    export "${fout_name:=${1:-fout}}=${fout:=$(date): $((a=${a:-50}+1)) $((b=${b:-100}-4))}"
    printf %s\\n "$fout"
}

f &&
    printf %s\\n \
        "$fout_name" \
        "$fout" \
        "$a" "$b"
```

I've provided a better formatted example below, but, called as above the output is:

```
sh: line 2: 2: invalid or unspecified param - name set to fout
Wed Jul  2 02:27:07 PDT 2014: 51 96
fout
Wed Jul  2 02:27:07 PDT 2014: 51 96
51
96
```

Or with different `$ENV` or arguments:

```
b=9 f myvar &&
    printf %s\\n \
        "$fout_name" \
        "$fout" \
        "$myvar" \
        "$a" "$b"

###OUTPUT###

Tue Jul  1 19:56:42 PDT 2014: 52 5
myvar
Tue Jul  1 19:56:42 PDT 2014: 52 5
Tue Jul  1 19:56:42 PDT 2014: 52 5
52
5
```

Probably the trickiest thing to get right when it comes to twice evaluating is to ensure that variables don't break quotes and execute random code. The more times a variable is evaluated the harder it gets. Parameter expansion helps a great deal here, and using `export` as opposed to `eval` is far safer.

In the above example `f()` first assigns `$fout` the `''` null string and then sets positional params to test for valid variable names. If both tests do not pass a message is emitted to `stderr` and the default value of `fout` is assigned to `$fout_name`. Regardless of the tests, however, `$fout_name` is always assigned to either `fout` or the name you specify and `$fout` and, optionally, your specified name are always assigned the output value of the function.
To demonstrate this I wrote this little `for` loop:

```
for v in var '' "wr;\' ong"
    do sleep 10 &&
        a=${a:+$((a*2))} f "$v" || break
    echo "${v:-'' #null}" 
    printf '#\t"$%s" = '"'%s'\n" \
        a "$a" b "$b" \
        fout_name "$fout_name" \
        fout "$fout" \
        '(eval '\''echo "$'\''"$fout_name"\")' \
            "$(eval 'echo "$'"$fout_name"\")"
 done
```

It plays around some with variable names and parameter expansions. If you have a question just ask. That *only* runs the same few lines in the function already represented here. It's worth mentioning at least though that the `$a` and `$b` variables behave differently depending on whether they are defined at invocation, or set already. Still, the `for` does almost nothing but format the data set and provided by `f()`. Have a look:

```
###OUTPUT###

Wed Jul  2 02:50:17 PDT 2014: 51 96
var
#       "$a" = '51'
#       "$b" = '96'
#       "$fout_name" = 'var'
#       "$fout" = 'Wed Jul  2 02:50:17 PDT 2014: 51 96'
#       "$(eval 'echo "$'"$fout_name"\")" = 'Wed Jul  2 02:50:17 PDT 2014: 51 96'
sh: line 2: 2: invalid or unspecified param - name set to fout
Wed Jul  2 02:50:27 PDT 2014: 103 92
'' #null
#       "$a" = '103'
#       "$b" = '92'
#       "$fout_name" = 'fout'
#       "$fout" = 'Wed Jul  2 02:50:27 PDT 2014: 103 92'
#       "$(eval 'echo "$'"$fout_name"\")" = 'Wed Jul  2 02:50:27 PDT 2014: 103 92'
sh: line 2: 2: invalid or unspecified param - name set to fout
Wed Jul  2 02:50:37 PDT 2014: 207 88
wr;\' ong
#       "$a" = '207'
#       "$b" = '88'
#       "$fout_name" = 'fout'
#       "$fout" = 'Wed Jul  2 02:50:37 PDT 2014: 207 88'
#       "$(eval 'echo "$'"$fout_name"\")" = 'Wed Jul  2 02:50:37 PDT 2014: 207 88'
```