# tee into different variables

Tags: bash, variable, file-descriptors, tee

From the bash code

```
command1 | tee >(command2) | command3
```

I want to capture the output of `command2` in `var2` and the output of `command3` in `var3`.

`command1` is I/O-bound and the other commands are costly but can start working before `command1` finishes.

The order of outputs from `command2` and `command3` are not fixed. So I tried to use file-descriptors in

```
read -r var2 <<< var3=(command1 | tee >(command2 >&3) | command3) 3>&1
```

or

```
{read -u 3 -r var2; read -r var3} <<< command1 | tee >(command2 >&3) | command3
```

but did not succed.

Is there a way to have the three commands run in parallel, store the results in different variables and not make temporary files?

Comment: It's hard to give a negative answer for sure, but I think that would require the shell reading from two pipes at a time, and I can't think of any shell feature that could do that (in Bash, that is). How large are your outputs?

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for the feedback! Each output is less than 4KB.

Comment: interesting, I tried using named pipes, but result were lost due to backgrounding ( `&` ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well all your requirements you could achieve that in `bash` by creating an unnamed pipe per command, then redirecting each command’s output to its respective unnamed pipe, and finally retrieving each output from its pipe into a separate variable.

As such, the solution might be like:

```bsh
: {pipe2}<> <(:)
: {pipe3}<> <(:)

command1 | tee >({ command2 ; echo EOF ; } >&${pipe2}) >({ command3 ; echo EOF ; } >&${pipe3}) > /dev/null &
var2=$(while read -ru ${pipe2} line ; do [ "${line}" = EOF ] && break ; echo "${line}" ; done)
var3=$(while read -ru ${pipe3} line ; do [ "${line}" = EOF ] && break ; echo "${line}" ; done)

exec {pipe2}<&- {pipe3}<&-
```

Here note particularly:

- the use of the `<(:)` construct; this is an undocumented Bash's trick to open "unnamed" pipes
- the use of a simple `echo EOF` as a way to notify the `while` loops that no more output will come. This is necessary because it's no use to just close the unnamed pipes (which would normally end any `while read` loop) because those pipes are bidirectional, ie used for both writing and reading. I know no way to open (or convert) them into the usual couple of file-descriptors one being the read-end and the other its write-end.

In this example I used a pure-bash approach (beside the use of `tee`) to better clarify the basic algorithm that is required by the use of these unnamed pipes, but you could do the two assignments with a couple of `sed` in place of the `while` loops, as in `var2="$(sed -ne '/^EOF$/q;p' <&${pipe2})"` for variable2 and its respective for variable3, yielding the same result with quite less typing. That is, the whole thing would be:

## Lean solution for small amount of data

```bsh
: {pipe2}<> <(:)
: {pipe3}<> <(:)

command1 | tee >({ command2 ; echo EOF ; } >&${pipe2}) >({ command3 ; echo EOF ; } >&${pipe3}) > /dev/null &
var2="$(sed -ne '/^EOF$/q;p' <&${pipe2})"
var3="$(sed -ne '/^EOF$/q;p' <&${pipe3})"

exec {pipe2}<&- {pipe3}<&-
```

In order to display the destination variables, remember to disable word splitting by clearing IFS, like this:

```bsh
IFS=
echo "${var2}"
echo "${var3}"
```

otherwise you’d lose newlines on output.

The above does look quite a clean solution indeed. Unfortunately it can only work for not-too-much output, and here your mileage may vary: on my tests I hit problems on around 530k of output. If you are within the (well very conservative) limit of 4k you should be all right.

The reason for that limit lies to the fact that two assignments like those, ie *command substitution* syntax, are synchronous operations, which means that the second assignment runs only after the first is finished, while on the contrary the `tee` feeds both commands simultaneously and blocking all of them if any happens to fill its receiving buffer. A deadlock.

The solution for this requires a slightly more complex script, in order to empty both buffers simultaneously. To this end, a `while` loop over the two pipes *would* come in handy.

## A more standard solution for any amount of data

A more standard Bashism is like:

```bsh
declare -a var2 var3
while read -r line ; do
   case "${line}" in
   cmd2:*) var2+=("${line#cmd2:}") ;;
   cmd3:*) var3+=("${line#cmd3:}") ;;
   esac
done < <(
   command1 | tee >(command2 | stdbuf -oL sed -re 's/^/cmd2:/') >(command3 | stdbuf -oL sed -re 's/^/cmd3:/') > /dev/null
)
```

Here you multiplex the lines from both commands onto the single standard “stdout” file-descriptor, and then subsequently demultiplex that merged output onto each respective variable.

Note particularly:

- the use of indexed arrays as destination variables: this is because just appending to a normal variable becomes horribly slow in presence of lots of output
- the use of `sed` commands to prepend each output line with the strings "cmd2:" or "cmd3:" (respectively) for the script to know which variable each line belongs to
- the necessary use of `stdbuf -oL` to set line-buffering for commands’ output: this is because the two commands here share the same output file-descriptor, and as such they would easily override each other’s output in the most typical race condition if they happen to stream out data at the same time; line-buffering output helps avoiding that
- note also that such use of stdbuf is only required for the last command of each chain, ie the one outputting directly to the shared file-descriptor, which in this case are the sed commands that prepend each commandX’s output with its distinguishing prefix

One safe way to properly display such indexed arrays can be like this:

```bsh
for ((i = 0; i < ${#var2[*]}; i++)) ; do
   echo "${var2[$i]}"
done
```

Of course you can also just use `"${var2[*]}"` as in:

```bsh
echo "${var2[*]}"
```

but that is not very efficient when there are many lines.

Comment: This is very interesting but what makes it better than `command1 | tee >(command2 | sed 's/^/cmd2:/') | command3 | sed 's/^/cmd3:/`.?

Comment: I tried to get it to work but failed to capture any output. How do I manage to store it in `var2` and `var3`?

Answer (score 4):

So you want to pipe the output of cmd1 into both cmd2 and cmd3 and get both the output of cmd2 and cmd3 into different variables?

Then it seems you need two pipes from the shell, one connected to cmd2's output and one to cmd3's output, and the shell to use `select()`/`poll()` to read from those two pipes.

`bash` won't do for that, you'd need a more advanced shell like `zsh`. `zsh` doesn't have a raw interface to `pipe()`, but if on Linux, you can use the fact that `/dev/fd/x` on a regular pipe acts like a named pipe and use a similar approach as that used at [Read / write to the same file descriptor with shell redirection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/472585)

```
#! /bin/zsh -

cmd1() seq 20
cmd2() sed 's/1/<&>/g'
cmd3() tr 0-9 A-J

zmodload zsh/zselect
zmodload zsh/system
typeset -A done out
{
  cmd1 > >(cmd2 >&3 3>&-) > >(cmd3 >&5 5>&-) 3>&- 5>&- &
  exec 4< /dev/fd/3 6< /dev/fd/5 3>&- 5>&-
  while ((! (done[4] && done[6]))) && zselect -A ready 4 6; do
    for fd (${(k)ready[(R)*r*]}) {
      sysread -i $fd && out[$fd]+=$REPLY || done[$fd]=1
    }
  done
} 3> >(:) 5> >(:)

printf '%s output: <%s>\n' cmd2 "$out[4]" cmd3 "$out[6]"
```

Comment: Why the `-` in the shebang?

Comment: @terdon, see [Why the "-" in the "#! /bin/sh -" shebang?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/351729)

Comment: Thank you for that crazy solution. I did not expect the problem to be this complicated. Sadly `zsh` is not an option for the project since not all users of the script will have it installed. But I can learn something from it anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I found something that seems to work nicely:

```
exec 3<> <(:)
var3=$(command1 | tee >(command2 >&3) | command3)
var2=$(while IFS= read -t .01 -r -u 3 line; do printf '%s\n' "$line"; done)
```

It works by setting an anonymous pipe `<(:)` to the file-descriptor 3 and piping the output of `command2` to it. `var3` captures the output of `command3` and the last line reads from the file-descriptor 3 until it does not receive any new data for 0.01 seconds.

It only works for an output of up to 65536 bytes of `command2` which seems to be buffered by the anonymous pipe.

I do not like the last line of the solution. I would rather read in everything at once and not wait for 0.01 seconds but stop as soon as the buffer is empty. But I do not know any better way.

Comment: The problem in your last line is that fd 3 does not actually get closed at the end of output, hence the ```read``` does not sense the eof event. See also my own updated answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable since 4.0. bash added a shell reserved word coproc. It forks the command that follows to the background as a sub process (which normally would not allow the passing of variables.) however it creates an array (defaulting to COPROC but can be named). ${COPROC[0]} connects to the standard input of the sub-process ${COPROC[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139713/417184)} its standard out.These process can be manipulated as jobs, are asynchronous so you can just use tee to pipe to the two coprocess and have them output to a separate file each then combine the outputs on the return value of each by calling "${COPROCFIRST[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139713/417184)} ${COPROCSECOND[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139713/417184)}" which is great because it doesnt even need to be within the pipeline.

<s>bash
coproc command_1 { command1 arg1 arg2 arg3 >> command_1_output.txt }
coproc command_2 { command2 arg1 arg2 arg3 >> command_2_output.txt }
othercommand | tee >^${command_1[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139713/417184)}" >&"${command_2[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139713/417184)}"
read -r results1 <&"${command_1[0]"
read -r resluts2 <&"${command_2[0]"
echo "$result1 $result2" | command3 >> combinedresult.txt</s>

As mentioned this solution is currently incomplete so I'm striking it, however the principle is sound and is similar in to the answer above. Hower i will direct you to some good articles on the subject and will return to this answer when work permits.

[Example of setting variables in a coprocess](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139713/417184)

[Indepth look at coprocess and named pipes](https://web.archive.org/web/20151221031303/http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/shell/co-processes.hints)

[Uses and Pitfalls](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc)

Comment: I find this confusing. (1) Answers are a ***WHOLE lot*** more readable when they use the same naming convention as the question.  It appears that you have renamed “command1” → “othercommand”, “command2” → “command1”, and “command3” → “command2”.  And yet you also have a “command3”, so clearly I’m not understanding you. (2) The question requests that there be no temporary files, and yet you clearly have some.  ISTM that this exercise is easy if you’re allowed to use temporary files.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) The question wants output into two variables.  Getting back to my point 1, I see no ``var2`` and ``var3`` — have you renamed them to `results1` and `results2`?  Are you assuming that each command will produce exactly one line of output?  (4) Again getting back to my point 1, *what **is*** `command3`?  What is `combinedresult.txt`?  The question *does **not*** call for an output file.  Why are you trying to “combine the outputs on the return value”?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) You clearly have not copied-and-pasted this from a tested, working solution, because the third line (the one with the ``tee``) has unbalanced quotes.  I’ll admit that I have rushed to post an answer to a new question in hopes of being the first to do so.  Rushing to post an untested answer to a three-year-old question is poor form. (6) At the risk of nit-picking, why are you using `>>` instead of `>`?

Comment: ah, I apologize was written on my break at work on cellphone updating now, I was working under the assumption that the output was meant to be saved (as in logs)  however if you look at the command the variables are not set using temporary files but are set by the values of the output of the co process commands called through their array.

Comment: However I use the >> instead of the > because co-process runs in a stream it reevaluates every time you feed it information and if you log your command out put (which i generally default too). Which is why i didn't consider them temporarily files as they a. aren't what sets the variable and b. aren't intended to be destroyed. I'm of work in in an hour and will write up better articulated solution.