# How to get both the number of bytes and the sha1sum with single pass?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh

I want to get both the number of bytes and the sha1sum of a command's output.

In principle, one can always do something like:

```
BYTES="$( somecommand | wc -c )"
DIGEST="$( somecommand | sha1sum | sed 's/ .*//' )"
```

...but, for the use-case I am interested in, `somecommand` is rather time-consuming, and produces a ton of output, so I'd prefer to call it only once.

One way that comes to mind would be something like

```
evil() {
  {
    somecommand | \
      tee >( wc -c | sed 's/^/BYTES=/' ) | \
      sha1sum | \
      sed 's/ .*//; s/^/DIGEST=/'
  } 2>&1
}

eval "$( evil )"
```

...which seems to work, but makes me die a little inside.

I wonder if there is a better (more robust, more general) way to capture the output of different segments of a pipeline into separate variables.

EDIT: The problem I am working on at the moment is in `bash`, so I am mostly interested in solutions for this shell, but I do a lot of `zsh` programming also, so I have some interest in those solutions as well.

EDIT2: I tried to port Stéphane Chazelas' solution to `bash`, but it didn't quite work:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd() {
    printf -- '%1000s'
}

bytes_and_checksum() {
    local IFS
    cmd | tee >(sha1sum > $1) | wc -c | read bytes || return
    read checksum rest_ignored < $1 || return
}

set -o pipefail
unset bytes checksum
bytes_and_checksum "$(mktemp)"
printf -- 'bytes=%s\n' $bytes
printf -- 'checksum=%s\n' $checksum
```

When I run the script above, the output I get is

```
bytes=
checksum=96d89030c1473585f16ec7a52050b410e44dd332
```

The value of `checksum` is correct.  I can't figure out why the value of `bytes` is not set.

EDIT3: OK, thanks to @muru's tip, I fixed the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd() {
    printf -- '%1000s'
}

bytes_and_checksum() {
    local IFS
    read bytes < <( cmd | tee >(sha1sum > $1) | wc -c ) || return
    read checksum rest_ignored < $1 || return
}

set -o pipefail
unset bytes checksum
bytes_and_checksum "$(mktemp)"
printf -- 'bytes=%s\n' $bytes
printf -- 'checksum=%s\n' $checksum
```

Now:

```
bytes=1000
checksum=96d89030c1473585f16ec7a52050b410e44dd332
```

### <strike>**UNFORTUNATELY**...</strike>

<strike>...my `bytes_and_checksum` function stalls (deadlock?) when `cmd` produces a lot more output than was the case in my toy example above.</strike>

<strike>Back to the drawing board...</strike>

Comment: why don't you just save the output of `somecommand` in a variable, or write it to a temporary file if it's prohibitively large?

Comment: and why the `eval`? simply call your function.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: regardiing your second question, the code is meant to be part of a larger script, which will go on to to stuff with `BYTES` and `DIGEST`.

Comment: For your edit: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/143958/70524

Comment: for `cmd | read bytes` to work in bash, you need `shopt -s lastpipe` with `set +o monitor`

Comment: I can't reproduce your *stalling* with bash 5.2

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thank you for looking into it.  I will re-check and report back.

Comment: `ps` would help to show which processes hang around, and `strace` what they're doing/waiting for.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Apologies! I too cannot reproduce the stalling I claimed earlier.  More precisely, I no longer have the code that exhibited the stalling I reported earlier, and every attempt I've made to reconstruct it from memory has resulted in code that produces the correct result in a reasonable time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would be easier to use temp files. In `zsh`:

```
(){set -o localoptions -o pipefail; local IFS
  {cmd} > >(sha1sum > $1) | wc -c | read bytes || return
  read checksum rest_ignored < $1 || return
} =()
```

Beware many `wc` implementations include whitespace around the number they output. `read` with the default value of `$IFS` strips them.

Note that the exit status of `sha1sum` is lost.

There `=()` creates the temp file with the non-output of nothing at all. That temp file is removed automatically when the command it's given to (here an anonymous function) returns.

In `cmd > file | other-cmd`, `cmd`'s output is `tee`d internally by `zsh` since it's redirected twice, so here both to `sha1sum` and to `wc`. We wrap `cmd` in `{...}` to make sure zsh waits for the process-redirections to finish.

Here as the output of both `sha1sum` and `wc` is guaranteed to be no larger than a few bytes, they could also be sent to pipes, and you would not have to read from those pipes concurrently (which zsh can do as it has an interface to `select()`/`poll()` but not bash). That could be done sequentially without causing deadlocks, so it's an easy version of [tee into different variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/507061).

On Linux-based systems (where `/dev/fd/x` when `x` is a fd to a pipe behaves like a named pipe):

```
{
  IFS=$' \t' read bytes < <(cmd 3<&- | tee >(sha1sum > /dev/fd/3) | wc -c)
  IFS=$' \t' read sum rest <&3
} 3< <(:)
```

(would even work in bash).

For details about the deadlocks you'd run into with larger outputs, see also [tee + cat: use an output several times and then concatenate results](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/66853).

Comment: I delete my previous comment, since it is now mostly obsolete, except for the "thank you" part.  So, thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

I am using a backup **bash** script which has the following helper "in-between" functions which take a "supposed filename" as an argument (see tar.gz example below):

```bash
function pipesum
{
  tee >(sha1sum | awk --assign F="${1##*/}" '$2=F' > "${1?}.sha1")
}
function pipelen
{
  tee >(wc -c > "${1?}.len")
}
function pipesumlen
{
  tee >(sha1sum | awk --assign F="${1##*/}" '$2=F' > "${1?}.sha1") >(wc -c > "${1?}.len")
}
function pipechecksum
{
  tee >(sha1sum --quiet -c <(awk '$2="-"' "${1?}") >&2)
}
```

Example:

```
$ echo 123 | pipesumlen filename
123
$ ls filename*
filename.len  filename.sha1
$ cat filename*
4
a8fdc205a9f19cc1c7507a60c4f01b13d11d7fd0 filename
$ echo 123 | pipechecksum filename.sha1
123
$ echo 1234 | pipechecksum filename.sha1
1234
-: FAILED
sha1sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
```

I am using it in a script which is very time, CPU and IO consuming, something like that:

```bash
tar | 
  pipesumlen mybackup.tar | 
  gzip > mybackup.tar.gz
<mybackup.tar.gz gunzip | 
  pipechecksum mybackup.tar.sha1 | 
  xz > mybackup.tar.xz
```

Thus I have my backup checked against random memory/disk bit flips. It creates the "mybackup.tar.sha1" file as if the "mybackup.tar" was actually created and checksummed while in truth in this example the uncompressed data is never written on disk.

Caveat: the `pipechecksum` does not terminates the script on error even with `set -euo pipefail`. The alternative `pipechecksum` which does return nonzero on checksum mismatch:

```bash
function pipechecksum
{
  { tee /dev/fd/$N | sha1sum --quiet -c <(awk '$2="-"' "${1?}") >&2; } {N}>&1
}
```

It seems fine, but I've came with it just today and cannot consider it proven.